# How to fix ERROR TypeError: t.rgb is not a function In ngx-charts heat map graph

Tags: angular, typescript, rgb, heatmap, ngx-charts

I'm trying to create a heap map using ngx-charts, the graph is up and running but the colors of the graph is not shown because of an RGB error in the library. Any suggestions to solve this issue?

Here is an Image of the chart with no colors. These bars should be filled with colors. Found that `d3js` is used as a dependency on ngx-charts

[image]

Error message in console -

```
main-es2015.c512fe386c6a4d3e4777.js:1 ERROR TypeError: t.rgb is not a function
    at _ (main-es2015.c512fe386c6a4d3e4777.js:1)
    at w (main-es2015.c512fe386c6a4d3e4777.js:1)
    at i (main-es2015.c512fe386c6a4d3e4777.js:1)
    at b (main-es2015.c512fe386c6a4d3e4777.js:1)
    at y (main-es2015.c512fe386c6a4d3e4777.js:1)
    at t.f [as scale] (main-es2015.c512fe386c6a4d3e4777.js:1)
    at t.getColor (main-es2015.c512fe386c6a4d3e4777.js:1)
    at main-es2015.c512fe386c6a4d3e4777.js:1
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at main-es2015.c512fe386c6a4d3e4777.js:1
```

Link for the issue in GitHub - [link to issue](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/issues/1291)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated version of @angular-devkit/build-angular from 0.800.0 to 0.803.17 solved the issue.

solved with the help of Michael Kopf's answer on github [link to answer](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/issues/1291)

Answer (score -1):

it has nothing to do with typescript, typescript doesn't affect runtime.

the `TypeError` exception was raised because `t.rgb` wasn't a function literally during runtime. try to add breakpoints in your code and see if anything goes wrong.